# Is it possible to integrate GWT on a website builder?

Tags: gwt

I want to integrate my gwt code to a website builder, because my gwt code has an embedded database system. Is it possible to integrate gwt to a website builder?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more info than that to have something to answer besides "It depends.". You already have GWT code, and it uses an embedded database - can you provide a lot more detail? Can you describe what your existing GWT code does, and what you intend this website builder to do?

Comment: my friend request to me to add a database system on his website... my friend doesnt know anything about programming... and im new to programming... so i create a gwt code so that when the sign up button from a website builder is clicked will go to my deployed gwt on tomcat and input data to database..

i want to know if instead of going to my deployed gwt... is there a way that i will only copy the sign up functions from my gwt to the sign up button of the website builder? i know that gwt converts java code to java script... i only know java... also im new to website builder

Comment: @George, it would be better to add all the details to your question rather than in your comments!